# SWT/JFace TableViewer not showing Unicode characters

Tags: java, swt, jface, utf

I'm using a `TableViewer` for showing some data in my app. The problem is that this widget is not showing Unicode characters, and I don't understand why?
Is there a way to solve this?

Edit: I've made a debugging session. I think the problem isn't the Table, but the `ArrayList` where strings are stored.
The program loads a `byte[]` array and decodes it, generating Unicode strings. In my previous app it appears that the list is correctly stored, but in the new one (with the same way to generate strings) unicode special characters like 'è' are not stored correctly. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it ;)
The trick was to use UTF-8 instead of UTF-16 (Eclipse did the job for me)